# How can I import MapBox in Unity 2019.3.0a6?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, mapbox-android

I tried importing the latest MapBox into Unity but the error "Component of type GUI Layer is no longer available in Unity. References to it will be removed!" I want to import MapBox and have it as a dropdown menu like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l850.jpg

Answer (score 2):

[GUI Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUILayer.html)
Is now a legacy code, also take a look here https://forum.unity.com/threads/removing-the-guilayer-guitext-guitexture-components.608770/

I think you need to wait till the package developers update their package, or use a previous version of unity

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed the ARFoundation and ARCore or ARKit packages from the Unity Package Manager?

Comment: Can you answer without this clarification question answered beforehand?